# Using LDAP with hyperledger composer

Tags: ldap, passport.js, hyperledger-composer

I am using following LDAP configuration for ldap passport strategy with hyperledger composer:

```
     export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
      "ldap": {
      "provider": "ldap",
      "authScheme": "ldap",
      "module": "passport-ldapauth",
      "authPath": "/auth/ldap",
      "callbackURL": "/auth/ldap/callback",
      "successRedirect": "/",
      "failureRedirect": "/",
      "server": {  
         "url": "ldap://localhost:389",
         "bindDn": "cn=admin,dc=example, dc=com",
         "bindCredentials": "*****",
         "searchBase": "ou=admin,dc=example,dc=com",
         "searchFilter": "(uid={{username}})"
       }
    }
  }'
```

In github authentication we usually have to go to http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback and login to github. Now here in this case what shall I give in web url so that I will get the authentication token. http://localhost:3000/auth/ldap/callback does not result in anything. So is it that I need to pass the existing username  in ldap, in web url ? If yes, then what should be that URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you use callback for passport-ldapauth

so

```
export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
      "provider": "ldap",
      "authScheme":"ldap",
      "module": "passport-ldapauth",
      "authPath": "/auth/ldap",
    "successRedirect": "/auth/account",
    "failureRedirect": "/ldap",
    "session": false,
    "json": true,
    "profileAttributesFromLDAP": {
      "login": "uid",
      "username": "uid",
      "displayName": "displayName",
      "email": "mail",
      "externalId": "uid"
     },
    "ldap_attribute_for_login": "uid",
    "ldap_attribute_for_username": "uid",
    "ldap_attribute_for_mail": "mail",
      "server":{
        "url": "ldap://localhost:389",
         "bindDn": "cn=admin,dc=example, dc=com",
         "bindCredentials": "*****",
         "searchBase": "ou=admin,dc=example,dc=com",
         "searchAttributes": ["cn", "mail", "uid", "givenname"],
         "searchFilter": "(uid={{username}})"
        "url": "ldap://ldap.example.org:389/dc=example,dc=org",
        "searchBase": "ou=people,dc=example,dc=org",

        "searchFilter": "(uid={{username}})"
      }
  }'
```

where

- authScheme should be set to ldap module should be set to
  passport-ldapauth
- authPath is the path for the authentication. i.e.
  the front-end will send a POST request to /auth/ldap
  consisting of the username and password
- successRedirect is the path to be redirected to if authentication succeeds. However, this is  overrided by “json”: true.
- “json”:true will mean that Loopback will return a JSON response consisting of the token and userId instead of redirecting. Implying this is done by 'something else' such as the front-end
- failureRedirect is the path to be redirected to if authentication fails
- session is set to false - won't be using session
- profileAttributesFromLDAP - in the profileAttributesFromLDAP section, if needed, we have configured the mapping to get:

  - login, username and externalId from LDAP's uid,
  - displayName from LDAP's displayName
  - email from LDAP's mail

    added here if this is required
- ldap_attribute_for_login/username/mail will need to be matched to the
  LDAP server equivalents
- server consists of an object with the LDAP server properties

see also resources and comment below https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth and https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/pull/44#issue-31347869